# Why use the "system font stack" rather than a generic font family?

Tags: fonts, css

I recently read two articles about the "system font stack" [[1](https://bitsofco.de/the-new-system-font-stack/)] [[2](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/system-font-stack/)]. Briefly, this is a list of font families designed to pick the system font on the reader's device. So the same page appears to use Apple defaults on an Mac, Windows defaults on a PC, and so on.

But generic font families `serif` and `sans-serif` already exist. Why is this not good enough? (Plus this would avoid needing to update the "stack".)

A few of my guesses:

- "Serif" may contradict a sans-serif system font, and vice versa.
- Browser vendor defaults may be independent of OS vendor defaults (unless `system-ui` becomes a new generic font family?)
- ...but nothing like this is explicitly stated in these and similar articles I could find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since these articles were published, `system-ui` has in fact become a generic font family. [The definition states:](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts-4/#system-ui-def)

> The purpose of system-ui is to allow web content to integrate with the look and feel of the native OS.

And notes:

> A cross-platform UA should use different fonts on its different supported platforms.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is why would anyone use a font other than the system default, there are many reasons, among them:

- To have more control as to how text is presented cross-platform.
- System font does not match the brand
- To have a more distinctive and unique look
- System font does not have the character support needed
- System font does not have the features/ weights needed

Comment: My question was more why WOULD you use the OS font, rather than the browser's serif or sans-serif. It appears some people want their website to feel OS-native on all devices (which I now appreciate).